# queue structure in C. Accessing pointer in a struct by de-refrencing pointer to that struct

Tags: c, queue, pointer-to-pointer

```
1.  struct node {
2.      char data;
3.      struct node* nxtPtr;
4.  }
5. 
6.  typedef struct node Node;
7.
8.  Node* front = NULL;
9.  Node* end = NULL;
10.
11. void enqueue(char userData)
12. {
13.     Node* temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
14.     temp->data = userData;
15.     temp->nxtPtr = ???
16. }
```

I have kept the code to a minimum to try and avoid confusion. Eventually the variable end will point to a Node structure containing a data element and a Node pointer element. On line 15 I would like to de-reference end to access the value stored in nxtPtr from the current end Node. However the following line

```
temp->nxtPtr = *end->nxtPtr;
```

gives the following gcc error

```
  incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct node *’ from type ‘struct node’
```

Answer (score 1):

The `A->B` means "the `B` field of the `struct` that `A` points to", so you don't need the `*`.

Comment: Thanks, I also just realised that I have made a misjudgment with the queue structure. I will ask for the question to be deleted. Thanks for your help